# Passing an Enum as an argument

Tags: c#, types, parameters, enumeration

I am playing around with trying to make a simple Roguelike game to learn C# a bit better. I am trying to make a general method that I can give it an Enum as an argument, and it will return how many elements are in that Enum as an int. I need to make it as general as possible, because I will have several different classes calling the method.

I have searched around for the last hour or so, but I couldn't find any resources here or otherwise that quite answered my question... I'm still at a beginner-intermediate stage for C#, so I am still learning all the syntax for things, but here is what I have so far:

```
// Type of element
public enum ELEMENT
{
    FIRE, WATER, AIR, EARTH
}


// Counts how many different members exist in the enum type
public int countElements(Enum e)
{
    return Enum.GetNames(e.GetType()).Length;
}


// Call above function
public void foo()
{
    int num = countElements(ELEMENT);
}
```

It compiles with the error "Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Enum'". I kind of see why it won't work but I just need some direction to set everything up correctly.

Thanks!

PS: Is it possible to change the contents of an enum at runtime? While the program is executing?

Comment: What would be the purpose of modifying an enum at run-time?  No code would be using added values, and code using modified/removed values would break.  If you want to have lists of data elements that can be dynamically changed at runtime, use a database.

Comment: I'm trying to emulate Dwarf Fortress on a smaller scale. You can change all sorts of stuff via some kind of flat text files that the game parses through on startup. Not sure how exactly they have it set up, although my guess is that if you have to hardcode Enums to work with them, then it wouldn't be with them... a dictionary perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int countElements(Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsEnum)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    return Enum.GetNames(type).Length;
}

public void foo()
{
    int num = countElements(typeof(ELEMENT));
}
```

Comment: Anthony: Perfect, compiles and works as expected. :D


David: I'm trying to emulate Dwarf Fortress on a smaller scale. You can change all sorts of stuff via some kind of flat text files that the game parses through on startup. Not sure how exactly they have it set up, although my guess is that if you have to hardcode Enums to work with them, then it wouldn't be with them.

Comment: I didn't know about the IsEnum on a type and it's been around since 4.0.  That's nice to have.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this with a generic method. Personally I like the syntax better for the `foo()` method this way, since you don't have to specify `typeof()`

```
    // Counts how many different members exist in the enum type
    public int countElements<T>()
    {
        if(!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("T must be an Enum");
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).Length;
    }

    // Call above function
    public void foo()
    {
        int num = countElements<ELEMENT>();
    }
```