# Referring to an enum value generically?

Tags: c#, enums

I have multiple `enum` in my application that enumerate multiple various machine states. At some point a command and a state is passed to an IO class that should simply take the command and enum value (as an int) and write it to the IO port.

I am trying to devise a function declaration that takes and `enum` value, though not from an specific `enum`. I know that I could have it take an `int` value and just use that but I would like the user of the function to be forced to pass and `enum` value. Is this possible?

```
public void WriteCommand(String command, int value)  // Works technically
public void WriteCommand(String command, enum value) // Forces enum value to be passed
```

Just to be clear say I have two enums

```
public enum MyEnum1 { VALUE1, VALUE2 };
public enum MyEnum2 { VALUE3, VALUE4 };
```

I want to be able to pass values from each enum to the function like so

```
WriteCommand("DoSomething", MyEnum1.VALUE1);
WriteCommand("DoSomething", MyEnum2.VALUE3);
```

Once received I would then cast the `enum` value to an int for writing.

Comment: Why don't you make multiple interfaces, based on the command? They can all call the same (private or whatever) base method that takes the `int`.

Comment: Why not stick with the `int value` and use static classes with readonly properties instead? For example, you could replace your `MyEnum1` with a corresponding static class with properties `Value1, Value2` and assign your ints to it.

Comment: take a look at his It maybe what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021249/passing-an-enum-as-an-argument

Comment: So the IO class would implement multiple interfaces (`ICommand1Writer`, `ICommand2Writer`, etc) where each interface has the specific function signature to the commands `enum` type? I guess that would work, I was just trying to reduce code, not add many more interfaces. But thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code from

```
public void WriteCommand(String command, enum value) // Forces enum value to be passed
```

to

```
public void WriteCommand(String command, Enum value) // Forces enum value to be passed
```

and you will be happy ;-)

[`System.Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) represents the base class of all created enumerations. So you will be able to pass in any created enumeration but nothing else.

You should also be aware of the following:

> If no underlying type is explicitly declared, Int32 is used.

So it may be the case, that you catch an enumeration where the base class is not an `Int32`. In this case you should take care about how you interpret and cast the value before writing it to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the parameter `Enum`.

Comment: Well would you look at that. // I've also been slight confused between usage of `double` versus `Double` or `bool` versus `Boolean`. What is the name of what this difference is? Why are some types capitalized and others not?

Comment: @KDecker `Enum` is the name of a type.  `enum` is a keyword, and is not a type at all.

Comment: @KDecker `double` is an alias for `Double`, but as Servy says here that doesn't apply to `enum` and `Enum`.

Comment: Hmm, though it doesn't seem that I can cast `Enum` to an `int`? EDIT: `Convert.ToInt32` looks like it should work.

Comment: @KDecker Just cast it to `object` first.

Answer (score -2):

If You wanna be strict about it :

```
 public void WriteCommand(String command, Enum value) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
```

Or more generic, that accepts int, and other value types

```
public void WriteCommand<T>(String command, T value) where T : struct 
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: That's even *more* permissive in what it accepts.

Comment: @Servy sorry - what's wrong with it ?

Comment: You can pass all sorts of things that aren't enums, and it need to accept only enums.

Comment: ok, I misread the question. Thought that he needs 2 versions, taking int's or enums..